# permitted_uri_chars codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-url

how to make sign @ can be use in the uri.  When i try to send an Email address in the url this message came

```
An Error Was Encountered

The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.
```

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The allowed uri characters are defined in `config.php`

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-@';
```